# Sas Excel output column value start with =

Tags: excel, sas, char, proc, ods

ECEMBER 8 2022, 9:16 PM
Can anyone suggest on Excel output having column with spacial char ..output file gets corrupted as column value start with = sign for some rows other having + or other spacial chars

Excel ods output having column value start with spacial char like += etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you had a look at 
 [ODS ESCAPECHAR](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug07/cc/cc18.pdf)?

Comment: Don't want to skip any value in this column ...it's just Excel is treating the value as formula

Comment: @RaviSharma  You still need to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `(formulas='off')`

Example:

```
data have;
  cell = '=hello there';
run;

ods excel file='funky-town.xlsx' options(formulas='off');

proc print data=have;
run;

ods excel close;
```

[image]